# Print lines between two patterns, pausing until keypress after each chunk

Tags: awk, sed, output

My `sed` or `awk` can print line between two patterns, but how can I make it display one by one?

Example - It should display the first part of the output, and when I press <kbd>Space</kbd> it should display the 2nd part of the output, and so on until it has displayed all parts matching the pattern.

```
---------------------START HERE--------------------
Server Name : ABC 
xxxx 
xxxx 
xxxx 
xxxx 
---------------------END HERE---------------------- 

---------------------START HERE--------------------
Server Name : XYZ 
YYYY 
YYYY 
YYYY 
---------------------END HERE--------------------
```

For a file containing the above information, how may I display the information one by one, with a break/pause between until I press a key to show the next output.

My `sed` command

```
sed -n '/START/,/END/p' /tmp/output
```

displays everything at once.

Comment: Add your sed command to print lines between two patterns to your question.

Comment: `sed` and `awk` are designed for non-interactive usage, so you need to combine it with a different tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`, you can force the processing to "pause" when it hits the `END HERE` pattern:

```
sed -n -e '/START HERE/,/END HERE/{p' -e '/END HERE/r /dev/stdin' -e '}' file
```

or, as a `sed` script:

```
/START HERE/,/END HERE/ {
    p
    /END HERE/ r /dev/stdin
}
```

This simply tests for the `END HERE` pattern in the input and starts reading from standard input.  This temporarily halts the processing of the data until the `r` command is done.

You "unpause" by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

The same thing with `awk`:

```
awk '/START HERE/,/END HERE/ { print; if (/END HERE/) getline dummy <"/dev/stdin" }' file
```

Here, since we use `getline` to get input from the user, it's enough to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to display the next section of output.

Comment: Kusalananda . Thank you , Yes it work also .

Answer (score 0):

Are you ok with Python?

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput

show = False

for line in fileinput.input('a.txt'):
  if "START HERE" in line:
    show = True
    continue
  if "END HERE" in line:
    show = False
    try:
      input("Press ENTER to continue")
    except:
      pass
    print(chr(27) + "[2J") # Clear screen
    continue
  if show:
    print(line, end='')
```

Comment: HI , Fedor Dikarev  . I not familiar with python but I just search on how to call the python script  within shell script.  I will try that . Many Thank with your help.    But if someone else also can help to provide a shell script  also really appreciate.

Comment: HI , Fedor Dikarev . i'm using 2.7 phyton . so getting error on print(line, end='') - I fixed the issue (found from MR. google)   but there is a another issue   1. there is a space for each output.   2. it start read from 2nd output not the first output.  3. Error    Press ENTER to continue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./disp.py", line 14, in <module>
    input("Press ENTER to continue")
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: 4. how can i make this script read permanent file without to supply the input files.

Comment: 5. how to make a screen clear after each output or after press enter   ----absolutely_unused_variable = os.system("cls")

Comment: @BangauPutih I updated my answer: added `from __future__ import print_function`, add filename on `fileinput.input('a.txt'):`, add `try/except` block for `input` function, added print escape sequence to clear screeb.

Comment: Hi Fedor Dikarev;  it works perfect , I really really appreciate that. 4 star ✰✰✰✰   Thank you for your help.

Comment: @BangauPutih simply accept my answer ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: done ...so i need to learn python also.  :-)